# How to trigger the ALV DATA_CHANGE event manually?

Tags: abap, alv

I have an instance of `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID` referenced by variable `mo_alv_grid`.

I have a button column in this grid, which after some logic, updates the table `mt_alv_grid` (backing `mo_alv_grid`).

I need to be able to trigger the event `DATA_CHANGED` at this point.

I have tried many methods of `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID`, like `CHECK_DATA_CHANGED` and `REFRESH_TABLE_DISPLAY`
and even `CL_GUI_CFW=>FLUSH` and `CL_GUI_CFW=>SET_NEW_OK_CODE( 'ENTER' ).` but none of this has worked.

Is there a way to trigger the `DATA_CHANGED` event, or should I be doing things completely differently ?

Comment: Just to clarify - you have a button in the ALV grid that triggers ABAP code that changes the data in the backend internal table and want the display to be updated?

Comment: all of that, but the display IS updated, and I need to trigger DATA_CHANGED event automatically (not even hitting `ENTER` afterwards does it)

Comment: DATA_CHANGED is not supposed to be called if the data is updated programmatically, only when the USER changes the data.

Comment: Eventually I redesigned the whole thing :| thx anyway

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this solves your problem, but in order to update the ALV internal table in the PAI, you could use the following method:

```
DATA lv_entries_are_consisted TYPE abap_bool.
mo_grid->check_changed_data(
  IMPORTING
    e_valid = lv_entries_are_consisted
).
```

Answer (score 1):

well, it's possible.

1) don't change values in internal table by program
2) create a change protocol of type LVC_T_MODI with a new values for lines needed

then call

```
CALL METHOD lo_grid->change_data_from_inside
  EXPORTING
    it_style_cells = lt_cells.
```

where lo_grid is instance of cl_gui_alv_grid and lt_cells table type LVC_T_MODI. please note, that you will need to set field VAL_DATA of layout structure (LVC_S_LAYO) to 'X' when calling ALV grid for the first time to make this work.

after this, class will automatically change internal table for you and call DATA_CHANGE event