# Change Data of itab bound to CL_GUI_ALV_GRID programmatically and fire event DataChanged

Tags: event-handling, abap

I'm currently facing the following problem:
In my abap program I am using an ALV grid to display a list of data.
Now I have got the requirement to convert the data of cell 5 depending on the value entered in cell 3. Normally I could just do this by implementing a handler method for the DataChanged or DataChangedFinished events.

But in my case the value of cell 3 is written into the backend table i connected to the alv grid when creating it via the method SET_TABLE_FOR_FIRST_DISPLAY. That means the alv does not register it when the data is changed. I also tried to use the method CHANGE_DATA_FROM_INSIDE of CL_GUI_ALV_GRID and this partly works if I set the value of VAL_DATA in the layout structure to 'X' when initializing the grid. The program runs through my handler for the DataChanged event.
But in my case it results in a short dump because the method can only work with caracter fields and I need cell 3 and cell 5 to be decimals. The dump is caused in the GET_CHANGED_DATA method of CL_GUI_ALV_GRID. When I am applying this mechanism to character fields it works fine.

This question refers to the following thread where I got the idea of setting the VAL_DATA flag of the layout structure from:
[StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165710/how-to-trigger-the-data-change-event-of-cl-gui-alv-grid-or-why-isnt-it-trigger)

Did anyone ever face the same problem? Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: If the data change in cell 3 is performed on the ABAP side, why not change the value of cell 5 there as well and save yourself a round-trip? This would improve performance as well.

Comment: The DataChanged event is performed for character based fields. In my case cell 3 and cell 5 are decimals. When executing the method CHANGE_DATA_FROM_INSIDE a short dump is caused due to a conversion error of the decimals field. (I edited the title of this quesion, maybe i was not precise enought what my problem is about)

Comment: You wrote "But in my case the value of cell 3 is written into the backend table" - why don't you fill the cell 5 there as well?

Comment: That's sadly not possible because the conversion between cell 3 and cell 5 is a special logic that can not be applied to all occurences when this implementation that sets the value of cell 3 is used. It is encapsulated in a method that is reused several times in different applications. In this current application i need the conversion to be done. the other applications don't need it. that's the reason why i can't just adapt the code to make the conversion ad hoc. i need a general solution that can be used for future requirements as well.

Comment: Hi, could you post some code, so that one can really check in the system, what exactly the problem is? This would help a lot in helping you.

Comment: If You decide to inherit from CL_GUI_ALVGRID, You perhaps could achieve some things like this. You perhaps Could even inherit from You conversion class and redefine the conversion method in this particular case.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas.
AT Jagger: I don't think that it's helpful to post code. I described the coding as good as i'm able to. The code is encapsulated in different subroutines and methods.
AT icbytes: It's probably a way that would work. The problem is that the alv class is already used in the application and i'm not able to replace it with a custom class that inherited from the original.